# How to build an array of objects based on 2 differents objects in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 2 array of objects

```
public channelSelected: Array<Channel> = [];
public departmentSelected: Array<Department> = [];
```

Channel object has

```
 channelId?: string;
 name?: string;
```

and Department has

```
 channelId?: string;
 name?: string;
```

I want to create a new array of object that will be the "merge" of Channel and Department objects based on matching channelId

```
channelId?: string;
  names?: Array<string>;
```

expected output

```
"channels":[{
    "channelId": "9392823732",
     "names": ["Channel5", "Channel22", "Channel67"]
     },
     {
     "channelId": "332032",
     "names: ["Channel67", "Channel88", "Channel90"]
     }],
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an example payload?

Comment: It'd be better if you show an example of `input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood your question completely (it'd be better with an `input` for the `output`). I supposed that you wanted to match the `channelId` in both arrays in a single array:

```
interface Channel {
  channelId: string;
  name: string;
}

interface Department {
  channelId: string;
  name: string;
}

interface ChannelDepartment {
  channelId: string;
  names: string[];
}

const channelSelected: Channel[] = [
  {
    channelId: '9392823732',
    name: 'Channel5'
  },
  {
    channelId: '332032',
    name: 'Channel2'
  }
];
const departmentSelected: Department[] = [
  {
    channelId: '332032',
    name: 'Channel67'
  },
  {
    channelId: '2346',
    name: 'Channel34'
  }
];


const compareFn = (first: Channel | Department, second: Channel | Department): number => {
  if (first.channelId < second.channelId) return -1;

  if (first.channelId > second.channelId) return 1;

  return 0;
}

const channelDepartments = [...channelSelected, ...departmentSelected].sort(compareFn).reduce<ChannelDepartment[]>((previousValue, currentValue) => {
  const possibleChannelId = previousValue.find(item => item.channelId === currentValue.channelId);

  if (possibleChannelId) {
    possibleChannelId.names = [...possibleChannelId.names, currentValue.name];

    return previousValue;
  }

  return [...previousValue, {
    channelId: currentValue.channelId,
    names: [currentValue.name]
  }];
}, []);
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=50&pc=8#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAs4hBANsgbwFgAoZZBTbPASQBMAuZAZzClAHMBuU8kOALYQmrdiG6kAvqVKhIsRCgAiEAA5woYIeEK8KVHLnoi2nHmWT8hJsRJLSSs8NHhI0BvCvWbtYXRcosQ2MWU3FzPkEIZhtOAG0AXXMHUgQAexBWfSC8AGU8CARIRncc3ETkAF5kOL1iC3JA6iMSgHIATgBmdoAmAA4ezoB2Tp7WgBo9SOtkVowygFZWvUlJi3ryRo8WplbO0YAGUYmpyyjd%20eaxldIk1IysujUNLQhwfNxC4qYvF98K6q1danJrBNr7HpHMZrTZnGZzbYANiGywsqzqIO2IVagwALIiTg04cJZpdDJ1cajyA47o4SOlMn5QZ5nj43mBmFUagA6XnM3AfL4QOjjZC87lPbyvd4FIrChLcqDCgCuSAAPGSWVL-gkAHwACn1qiVADdgGllcwAGpwXDKiCihDKqBK8A2u0QACUVV1-kaDz8qjSzGYwAARp9NS0ucaIGaLdbbfbuTBQHR9cBIAIfchMxABNz%20fQqpVqk6Xez3cmi3RPeY9MAYMgjcHQxGIFH6N6NpsgyHw5GsXRuVZoly4uK%2023B2V6COosxHc7XWAqxB50JaaclWBnSBkLH45a1xFkCkLDu9wfTebj0n1wyEHAwPq4j2trOSuWV2vC0OYZso4xDU36VveG4QAkKwJHWUiiokdZAA)

Comment: interesting approach... shouldn't you sort [...channelSelected, ...departmentSelected] by channelId before reducing?

Comment: yes, because every reduce step is doing a find (which probably is some kind of iteration under the hood), but you are right, you don't need to

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
// create object for easy key access
const mergedChannelsObject = {}; 
channelSelected.forEach(item => {
  mergedChannelsObject[item.channelId] = item.names;
})
// loop, match on channelId and merge arrays
departmentSelected.forEach(item => {
  if (mergedChannelsObject.hasOwnProperty(item.channelId)) {
     mergedChannelsObject[item.channelId = [...mergedChannelsObject[item.channelId], ...item.names];
  } else {
    mergedChannelsObject[item.channelId] = item.names                           
  }
})
console.log(mergedChannelsObject);
// recreate an array
console.log('back to array: ', Object.entries(mergedChannelsObject).map(([key, item]) => {
   return { channelId: key, names: item }
}))

 `
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd leverage Rxjs [merge](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/merge), [groupBy](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/groupBy), [mergeMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeMap) and [reduce](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/reduce) to achieve the desired result

```
import { of, from, merge } from "rxjs";
import { map, groupBy, mergeMap,reduce } from "rxjs/operators";

interface IChannel {
  channelID?: string;
  name?: string;
}

interface IDepartment {
  channelID?: string;
  name?: string;
}

const channels: IChannel[] = [
  {
    channelID: "9392823732",
    name: "channel5"
  },
  {
    channelID: "332032",
    name: "Channel67"
  }
];
const departments: IDepartment[] = [
  {
    channelID: "9392823732",
    name: "Channel22"
  },
  {
    channelID: "9392823732",
    name: "Channel67"
  },
  {
    channelID: "332032",
    name: "Channel88"
  },
  {
    channelID: "332032",
    name: "Channel90"
  }
];

const merged = merge(from(channels), from(departments)).pipe(
  groupBy(item => item.channelID),
  mergeMap(groupedItem => groupedItem.pipe(
    reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, cur], []),
    map((list) => {
      let names = [];
      list.forEach((x)=>{
        names.push(x.name);
      })
      return {
        channelID:list[0].channelID,
        names:names,
      }
    })
  ))
);
merged.subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);
});
```

Here is a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xu89ah?embed=1&file=index.ts)

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
const channelSelected = [
    {
        channelId: '9392823732',
        names: ['Channel5', 'Channel22', 'Channel67']
    },
    {
        channelId: '234234654',
        names: ['Channel2', 'Channel33', 'Channel78']
    }
];

const departmentSelected = [
    {
        channelId: '332032',
        names: ['Channel67', 'Channel88', 'Channel90']
    },
    {
        channelId: '2346',
        names: ['Channel34', 'Channel234', 'Channel3450']
    }
];

const payload = channelSelected;

Array.prototype.push.apply(payload, departmentSelected); 

console.log(payload);
```

The result should be like this:
Codepen link: https://codepen.io/WIS-Graphics/pen/xxGwVxG

[image]

Comment: then you can just do const payload = [...channelSelected, ...departmentSelected]; No need to do fancy prototype thingy's. But the question is about matching channelIds.

Comment: Then merge the names values?